# Matlab: Plot graph to function

Tags: matlab, function, graph, plot, find

I am trying to figuring out how to plot graph to the following function:
[image]

Anyone that can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logical indexing! See [this link](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) for more information, logical indexing is a very useful thing to be familiar with when using Matlab!

```
x=0:0.01:2*pi; %// or whatever range of x you want
f=sin(x); %// calculate sin(x)
f(f<=0.5)=0.5; %// make the values of sin(x) less than or equal to 0.5 equal to 0.5
f(f>=0.7)=0.7;
plot(x,f) %// plot the result!
```